# How to configure Serilog MSSqlSink in net core 3 to use a different connection string for each web request?

Tags: sql-server, serilog, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .net core 3.1 multi-tenant Web API application which accesses single-tenant databases.  So each request acts on any one of the ***n*** databases.  I have the EF Core DbContext configured such that it resolves the connection string from a claim in the http request, but I do not know the correct approach to have a similar setup for Serilog's MSSqlSink.  Here's the abbreviated DbContext setup to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            // IHttpContextAccessor enables us to get at the claims
            var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
            var httpRequest = httpContext.Request;

            var claim = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "MyClaim");
            var customerIdentifier = claim.Value;
            var connectionString = GetConnectionString(customerIdentifier);

            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
```

So far, I've only been able to find examples for setting up Serilog's MSSqlSink with a known single connection string via appsettings or environment variables.

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't think it is possible out of the box. It batches logs so writing some logs to one DB and other to another would be tricky. I think you would need to fork or extend it.